# Django rest framework pagination with custom API view

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add pagination into my project, couldn't find any clear documentation or tutorial.

I have a list of offices

models
Office.py

```
class Office(Model):
    name = CharField(_("name"), default=None, max_length=255, null=True)
    email = EmailField(_("email"), default=None, max_length=255, null=True)
    description = TextField(_("description"), default=None, null=True)
```

Serializer

```
class OfficeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
     id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
     name = CharField(read_only=True)
     email = URLField(read_only=True)
     description = CharField(read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Office
    fields = ("id", "name", "email", "description")
```

views.py

```
@api_view(["GET"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def offices(request):
    instance = Office.objects.filter()[:10]
    serializer = OfficeSerializer(instance, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Any help with returning Office list with pagination ?

Comment: You can't get much clearer than the [Django pagination tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/)...

Comment: not for django rest @brianpck

Answer (score 26, accepted):

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

> Pagination is only performed automatically if you're using the generic
>   views or viewsets. If you're using a regular APIView, you'll need to
>   call into the pagination API yourself to ensure you return a paginated
>   response. See the source code for the mixins.ListModelMixin and
>   generics.GenericAPIView classes for an example.

https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L35
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L166

so I would suggest something like:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def offices(request):
    pagination_class = api_settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS
    paginator = pagination_class()
    queryset = Office.objects.all()
    page = paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, request)

    serializer = OfficeSerializer(page, many=True)

    return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: It seems like there is now a more generic way of doing it. A complete example can be found here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

Answer (score 1):

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

```
GET https://api.example.org/accounts/?limit=100&offset=400
```

Response:

```
HTTP 200 OK
{
    "count": 1023
    "next": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?limit=100&offset=500",
    "previous": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?limit=100&offset=300",
    "results": [
       …
    ]
}
```

Example of `settings.py`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'rest_framework_json_api.exceptions.exception_handler',
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS':
        'rest_framework_json_api.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_json_api.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_json_api.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    )
}
```

Comment: I saw this, adding the 2 line of code in setting.py doesn't work

Comment: It should work. I will post a different example, though.