# Django Rest 'PageNumberPagination' object has no attribute 'page' error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a function based Django API as shown in this sample:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def findData(request):
    dataId = request.GET['dataId']
    page_query_param = 'page'
    page_size = request.GET['page_size']
    paginator = PageNumberPagination()
    paginator.page_size = page_size
    paginator.page_query_param = page_query_param
    qry_set = Data.objects.all()
    serializer = dataIdSerializer(qry_set, many=True)
    theData= serializer.data
    return Response(paginator.get_paginated_response(theData))
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'PageNumberPagination' object has no attribute 'page'
```

I tried setting

```
paginator.page_query_param = page_query_param
```

But still same problem.  Please advise of how to fix.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use a vanilla view, and not just an `APIView` of the DRF (which can handle this autoamtically)?

Comment: Actually yes.   I am porting API from a C# rest; and the Frontend UI (outside my control) is basically making a call to end point findData.  I already have a ViewSet for the data, but I have to use a /findData endpoint.   Please advise if there is a way to use findData  + APIView, ViewSet or generics ... I can work with all if needed, I just need to do with a findData endpoint to the UI can still work.   Thank you

Comment: what exactly is the `dataId` doing here? It looks like you "throw away" that variable?

Comment: sorry it is a filter ... I simplified the example using .all, but the real qry has a filter (qry param) applied

Comment: Right now it looks like you are simply paginating all `Data` objects, so a simple `ListAPIView` will suffice here.

Comment: ListAPIView  is a class base.  Any suggestion on how to connect a specific endpoint (as /findData) to the class based implementation?

Comment: in the urls, you use `.as_view()`.

Comment: Thanks.  I never though of this.   I will give it a try and I will provide feedback.

Comment: perhaps the answer can be a starting point. You will however still have to fill in the `get_queryset` method with the filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely more effective to use a `ListView`, not only this will remove a lot of boilerplate code, but also is likely less error prone. You can just subclass the paginator to your own:

```
class MyPaginator(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 100
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000
```

Then in the `ListView`, we can make use of the `MyPaginator`:

```
from rest_framework import generics

class DataListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Data.objects.all()
    serializer_class = dataIdSerializer
    pagination_class = MyPaginator

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dataId = self.request.GET['dataId']
        super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            # …
        )
```

Here you can filter the queryset in the `get_queryset` method to only use `Data` objects that satisfy a given condition.

In the urls, you can then finally link it with `.as_view()`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/findData', DataListView.as_view())
]
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `page` is set on `PageNumberPagination` when `.paginate_queryset()` is called.

Therefore, you need to call `.paginate_queryset()` on your `paginator` and pass the `queryset` and the `request`.

When you instantiate your serializer, pass the result you got from calling `.paginate_queryset()` instead of `qry_set`

Once you're done with that, DRF will throw another exception since you put `paginator.get_paginated_response(theData)` in `Response`. To resolve that, just return `paginator.get_paginated_response(theData)`.

And finally your code will look like this:

```
def findData(request):
    dataId = request.GET['dataId']
    page_query_param = 'page'
    page_size = request.GET['page_size']
    paginator = PageNumberPagination()
    paginator.page_size = page_size
    paginator.page_query_param = page_query_param
    qry_set = Data.objects.all()
    p = paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset=qry_set, request=request) # change 1
    serializer = dataIdSerializer(p, many=True) # change 2
    theData= serializer.data
    return paginator.get_paginated_response(theData) # change 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot your answer saved a lot of time for me

Comment: Its better to do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40114426/12160182

Answer (score 0):

For me adding this to the `settings.py` fixed the issue.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10    # the size of one page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS & PAGE_SIZE values in REST_FRAMEWORK dictionary which is in settings.py of your project.

i.e

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
'PAGE_SIZE': 5
```

}